# How to move a player sprite By onScreenDigitalControl on autoparallexbackground in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game in andengine.i want to move a player sprite by onScreenDigitalControl on an autoparallex background.Can anyone tell me how to do that ???? thanks

Comment: The best way to get answers is to show some code you've written that is not working. Or at least show some effort that you tried to find an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code you can make player sprite moving by DigitalOnScreenControl. Also you can find many tutorials on this at http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/

public class TileActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

```
private TMXTiledMap mTMXTiledMap;
private BoundCamera mBoundChaseCamera;

private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 320;
private Scene mScene;

private static final long[] ANIMATE_DURATION = new long[]{200, 200, 200};
private static final int PLAYER_VELOCITY = 2;

private BitmapTextureAtlas mTexturePlayer;
private Body mPlayerBody;
private TiledTextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;
private BitmapTextureAtlas mOnScreenControlTexture;
private TextureRegion mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion;
private TextureRegion mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion;
private DigitalOnScreenControl mDigitalOnScreenControl;
private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;

private enum PlayerDirection{
    NONE,
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}
private PlayerDirection playerDirection = PlayerDirection.NONE;


@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    this.mBoundChaseCamera = new BoundCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mBoundChaseCamera));
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    // Control texture
    this.mOnScreenControlTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this, "onscreen_control_base.png", 0, 0);
    this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this, "onscreen_control_knob.png", 128, 0);

    // Player sprite texture
    this.mTexturePlayer = new BitmapTextureAtlas(128, 128, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
    this.mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mTexturePlayer, this, "hero.png", 0, 0, 3, 4);

    // Load the textures
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.mTexturePlayer, this.mOnScreenControlTexture);
}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    // Create physics world
    this.mPhysicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(30, new Vector2(0, 0), false, 8, 1);

    // Create the scene and register the physics world
    mScene = new Scene();
    mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

    // Load the TMX map
    try {
        final TMXLoader tmxLoader = new TMXLoader(this, this.mEngine.getTextureManager(), TextureOptions.NEAREST, null);
        this.mTMXTiledMap = tmxLoader.loadFromAsset(this, "test.tmx");
    } catch (final TMXLoadException tmxle) {
        Debug.e(tmxle);
    }

    // Add the non-object layers to the scene
    for (int i = 0; i < this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().size(); i++){
        TMXLayer layer = this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(i);
        if (!layer.getTMXLayerProperties().containsTMXProperty("wall", "true"))
        mScene.attachChild(layer);
    }

    // Read in the unwalkable blocks from the object layer and create boxes for each
    this.createUnwalkableObjects(mTMXTiledMap);

    // Make the camera not exceed the bounds of the TMXEntity.
    final TMXLayer tmxLayer = this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(0);
    this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBounds(0, tmxLayer.getWidth(), 0, tmxLayer.getHeight());
    this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBoundsEnabled(true);
    // Add outer walls
    this.addBounds(tmxLayer.getWidth(), tmxLayer.getHeight());

    // Calculate the coordinates for the player, so it's centred on the camera.
    final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getTileWidth()) / 2;
    final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mPlayerTextureRegion.getTileHeight()) / 2;

    // Create the player sprite and add it to the scene.
    final AnimatedSprite player = new AnimatedSprite(centerX, centerY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion);
    this.mBoundChaseCamera.setChaseEntity(player);
    final FixtureDef playerFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0.5f);
    mPlayerBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, player, BodyType.DynamicBody, playerFixtureDef);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(player, mPlayerBody, true, false){
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed){
            super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            mBoundChaseCamera.updateChaseEntity();
        }
    });
    mScene.attachChild(player);

    // Add the control
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl = new DigitalOnScreenControl(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion.getHeight(), this.mBoundChaseCamera, this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion, this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion, 0.1f, new IOnScreenControlListener() {
        @Override
        public void onControlChange(final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl, final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
            // Set the correct walking animation
            if (pValueY == 1){
                // Up
                if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.UP){
                    player.animate(ANIMATE_DURATION, 0, 2, true);
                    playerDirection = PlayerDirection.UP;
                }
            }else if (pValueY == -1){
                // Down
                if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.DOWN){
                    player.animate(ANIMATE_DURATION, 9, 11, true);
                    playerDirection = PlayerDirection.DOWN;
                }
            }else if (pValueX == -1){
                // Left
                if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.LEFT){
                    player.animate(ANIMATE_DURATION, 3, 5, true);
                    playerDirection = PlayerDirection.LEFT;
                }
            }else if (pValueX == 1){
                // Right
                if (playerDirection != PlayerDirection.RIGHT){
                    player.animate(ANIMATE_DURATION, 6, 8, true);
                    playerDirection = PlayerDirection.RIGHT;
                }
            }else{
                if (player.isAnimationRunning()){
                    player.stopAnimation();
                    playerDirection = PlayerDirection.NONE;
                }
            }
            // Set the player's velocity
            mPlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(pValueX * PLAYER_VELOCITY, pValueY * PLAYER_VELOCITY);
        }
    });
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.5f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScaleCenter(0, 128);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScale(1.25f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setScale(1.25f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setAlpha(0.5f);
    this.mDigitalOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();

    mScene.setChildScene(this.mDigitalOnScreenControl);

    return mScene;
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void createUnwalkableObjects(TMXTiledMap map){
    // Loop through the object groups
     for(final TMXObjectGroup group: this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXObjectGroups()) {
         if(group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty("wall", "true")){
             // This is our "wall" layer. Create the boxes from it
             for(final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) {
                final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(object.getX(), object.getY(),object.getWidth(), object.getHeight());
                final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 1f);
                PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody, boxFixtureDef);
                rect.setVisible(false);
                mScene.attachChild(rect);
             }
         }
     }
}

private void addBounds(float width, float height){
    final Shape bottom = new Rectangle(0, height - 2, width, 2);
    bottom.setVisible(false);
    final Shape top = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, 2);
    top.setVisible(false);
    final Shape left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, height);
    left.setVisible(false);
    final Shape right = new Rectangle(width - 2, 0, 2, height);
    right.setVisible(false);

    final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 1f);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, bottom, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, top, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

    this.mScene.attachChild(bottom);
    this.mScene.attachChild(top);
    this.mScene.attachChild(left);
    this.mScene.attachChild(right);
}
```

}